# Can't get the Enhanced Image plugin to work in Ckeditor in Rails 5.2.4 with Ruby 2.6.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am trying to add CkEditor in rails 5.2.4 with ruby 2.6.3. But getting issues while adding plugins. I want to use [Enhanced Image](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2) plugin.

Here are the details.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'
gem "mini_magick"
```

**asset.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[ckeditor/config.js]
```

**ckeditor.rb**

```
Ckeditor.setup do |config|
  require 'ckeditor/orm/active_record'
  config.cdn_url = '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.21.0/standard/ckeditor.js'
  config.js_config_url = 'ckeditor/config.js'
end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require ckeditor/config
//= require_tree .
```

**app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js**

```
if (typeof (CKEDITOR) != 'undefined') {
  CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar'

    config.height = '143px';
    config.width = '100%';
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.autoParagraph = false;
  }
}
```

Tried to add `config.extraPlugins = 'image2';` in Ckeditor config.js but it's not working.